# Proving a limit with a constant

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $cx_n \rightarrow ca$.

I'm comfortable doing so using the multiplicative properties of limits and utilizing the limit of a constanst, but how can I do this using the definition of limits?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $x_n \to a$ as $n\to \infty$. Assume $c\neq 0$. You want to prove that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$ you have $\lvert cx_n - ca\rvert < \epsilon$.

So we start with:

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Then note that
$$
\lvert cx_n - ca\rvert = \lvert c\rvert\cdot\lvert x_n - a\rvert.
$$
Now since $x_n \to a$ (for $n \to \infty$) you know by definition that there is an $n_0$ such that for $n\geq n_0$ you have 
$$
\lvert x_n - a\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{\lvert c \rvert}
$$
But this last inequality is exactly what you want because you can multiply by $\lvert c\rvert$ on both sides and there by get what you need.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I think where I run into trouble is looking to define $N$ here. I usually refer to it as $n_0$, but it trips me up when the given sequence is not explicitly defined.

Comment: @PaulGerard: I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, still working to strengthen my skills on these types of exercises

Answer (score 5):

HINT: There’s certainly no problem if $c=0$. If $c\ne 0$, note that $|ca-cx_n|=|c||a-x_n|$. If you make $|a-x_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$, you automatically make $|ca-cx_n|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\forall\,\epsilon >0\;:\;\;\;|cx_n-ca|=|c||x_n-a|<\epsilon\Longleftrightarrow |x_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}\,\,,\,c\neq 0$$

But you can find

$$N\in\Bbb N\,\,\,s.t.\,\,\,n>N\Longrightarrow |x_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{|c|}\ldots$$

The case $\,c=0\,$ I leave to you.